# Finding inteserction of two sets within two different dataframes grouping by some var

Tags: r, dplyr, plyr

I have these two dataframes:

**setA**:

```
   session_id            datetime request
        <int>              <dttm>   <dbl>
1        1105 2016-03-09 00:33:42       8
2        1105 2016-03-09 00:33:43       3
3        1107 2016-03-09 00:44:24      14
4        1107 2016-03-09 00:44:26      14
5        1108 2016-03-09 00:54:02       9
6        1108 2016-03-09 00:54:04      10
7        1109 2016-03-09 01:01:37      17
8        1109 2016-03-09 01:01:39       6
9        1110 2016-03-09 01:02:49      10
10       1110 2016-03-09 01:02:49       8
```

and **setB**:

```
   session_id            datetime request
        <int>              <dttm>   <dbl>
1        1105 2016-03-09 00:33:45       3
2        1107 2016-03-09 00:44:29       7
3        1108 2016-03-09 00:54:06      10
4        1109 2016-03-09 01:01:40       6
5        1110 2016-03-09 01:02:51       5
6        1111 2016-03-09 01:18:36      14
7        1111 2016-03-09 01:18:38      16
8        1112 2016-03-09 01:21:20       1
9        1112 2016-03-09 01:21:21      19
10       1114 2016-03-09 01:29:58      13
```

And Now i want to do some intersection on thse two sets but grouped by sessionid

Since sessionid 1105 in setA contains request (3,7) ,i want to do intersection with same sessionid i.e. 1105 containing request (3) in setB

```
calc = intersect(setA$request,setB$request)
```

...but grouped by sessionid.

I hope you get the idea.

Comment: Could you specify the output? You ask for `intersection` but the `datetimes` for the example you give are different. Do you want the `datetime` discarded? Or are you asking for a merge?

Comment: Discard datetime and i want length of that intersection based on request var

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can do this:

```
library(dplyr)
setA %>% 
  inner_join(setB, by = c("session_id", "request"))
```

This results in a merge of the dataframe where session_id and request are the same in both datasets, discarding the datetime.

```
  session_id request          datetime.x          datetime.y
1       1105       3 2016-03-09 00:33:43 2016-03-09 00:33:45
2       1108      10 2016-03-09 00:54:04 2016-03-09 00:54:06
3       1109       6 2016-03-09 01:01:39 2016-03-09 01:01:40
```

UPDATE: If you add this, you get the lengths of the intersections:

```
setA %>% 
  inner_join(setB, by = c("session_id", "request")) %>% 
  group_by(session_id) %>%
  summarise(lengthintersection = n())

  session_id lengthintersection
   <int>              <int>
1       1105                  1
2       1108                  1
3       1109                  1
```

UPDATE: as a response to the comment another update to calculate the proportions:

```
setA %>%
  group_by(session_id) %>% 
  mutate(numberrequests = n()) %>% 
  inner_join(setB, by = c("session_id", "request")) %>% 
  summarise(proportion = n()/numberrequests)

# A tibble: 3 x 2
      session_id proportion
        <int>      <dbl>
1       1105        0.5
2       1108        0.5
3       1109        0.5
```

Comment: ok good ,divide this lengthintersection with length of setA corressponding sessionIds length (i.e.  2 in 1105 case)...i'll mark as answer thanks.and god bless you Len

Comment: I am not sure what you mean. Would you like to know what proportion of requests in setA is in set B as well, grouped by sessionID? So for 1105 it should evaluate to 0.5?

Comment: Yes,you got it.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using the awesome data.table package, because for many tasks it is faster then dplyr.

I changed the example a little bit, so that there is an intersection with length > 1.

```
library(data.table)
A <- data.table("session_id" = c(1105, 1105, 1107 ,1107 ,1108, 1108, 1120),
                "request" = c(8,3,14,15,9,10, 20))
B <- data.table("session_id" = c(1105, 1107, 1107, 1108, 1109, 1110, 1111),
                "request" = c(3, 15, 14, 9, 6, 5, 9))
```

First, we perform a left outer join to get all the request values from table B:

```
C <- merge(A,B, all.x = T, by = "session_id")
```

Then we simply calculate the length of the intersection with the convenient "by" operation and join the result back to A:

```
C[, len_inter := length(intersect(request.x, request.y)), by=session_id]
A[C, len_inter := i.len_inter, on="session_id"]

> A
   session_id request len_inter
1:       1105       8         1
2:       1105       3         1
3:       1107      14         2
4:       1107      15         2
5:       1108       9         1
6:       1108      10         1
7:       1120      20         0
```

PS: In the future, please add some code to create your example data.frames, so that people don't have to manually type out your tables.